# jquery scrollbar | style tag vs style attribute

Tags: jquery, css, scrollbar

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.scrollcontainer1').scrollbar();
  $('.scrollcontainer2').scrollbar();
})
```

```css
.scrollcontainer1{
width:200px;
height:200px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.scrollbar/0.2.11/jquery.scrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.scrollbar/0.2.11/jquery.scrollbar.js"></script>
<h1>Width and height in style tag</h1>
<div class="scrollcontainer1 inner-scrollbar">
jniuniuiubiubiuiuhiuhiuuy hbubu ubiub ubiu uiiu jniuniuiubiubiuiuhiuhiuuy hbubu ubiub ubiu uiiu jniuniuiubiubiuiuhiuhiuuy hbubu ubiub ubiu uiiu jniuniuiubiubiuiuhiuhiuuy hbubu ubiub ubiu uiiu jniuniuiubiubiuiuhiuhiuuy hbubu ubiub ubiu uiiu jniuniuiubiubiuiuhiuhiuuy hbubu ubiub ubiu uiiu jniuniuiubiubiuiuhiuhiuuy hbubu ubiub ubiu uiiu
jniuniuiubiubiuiuhiuhiuuy hbubu ubiub ubiu uiiu jniuniuiubiubiuiuhiuhiuuy hbubu ubiub ubiu uiiu jniuniuiubiubiuiuhiuhiuuy hbubu ubiub ubiu uiiu jniuniuiubiubiuiuhiuhiuuy hbubu ubiub ubiu uiiu jniuniuiubiubiuiuhiuhiuuy hbubu ubiub ubiu uiiu jniuniuiubiubiuiuhiuhiuuy hbubu ubiub ubiu uiiu jniuniuiubiubiuiuhiuhiuuy hbubu ubiub ubiu uiiu
</div>
<h1>Width and height in style attr</h1>
<div class="scrollcontainer2 inner-scrollbar" style="width:200px;height:200px">
jniuniuiubiubiuiuhiuhiuuy hbubu ubiub ubiu uiiu jniuniuiubiubiuiuhiuhiuuy hbubu ubiub ubiu uiiu jniuniuiubiubiuiuhiuhiuuy hbubu ubiub ubiu uiiu jniuniuiubiubiuiuhiuhiuuy hbubu ubiub ubiu uiiu jniuniuiubiubiuiuhiuhiuuy hbubu ubiub ubiu uiiu jniuniuiubiubiuiuhiuhiuuy hbubu ubiub ubiu uiiu jniuniuiubiubiuiuhiuhiuuy hbubu ubiub ubiu uiiu
jniuniuiubiubiuiuhiuhiuuy hbubu ubiub ubiu uiiu jniuniuiubiubiuiuhiuhiuuy hbubu ubiub ubiu uiiu jniuniuiubiubiuiuhiuhiuuy hbubu ubiub ubiu uiiu jniuniuiubiubiuiuhiuhiuuy hbubu ubiub ubiu uiiu jniuniuiubiubiuiuhiuhiuuy hbubu ubiub ubiu uiiu jniuniuiubiubiuiuhiuhiuuy hbubu ubiub ubiu uiiu jniuniuiubiubiuiuhiuhiuuy hbubu ubiub ubiu uiiu
</div>
```

This is my question. When i use width and height in style attribute div width and height auto set to content width and height. But when I put width and height in style tag it is working. I want to change the width and height dynamically with php. So i want to use second method. Can you suggest a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this library overrides existing inline styles:

[image]

I think your safest bet is to catch those values from PHP with Javascript and dynamically change the divs heights **after** initializing scrollbar.

---

EDIT:

So I got interested in how to safely achieve this ability and looking at [the docs](http://gromo.github.io/jquery.scrollbar/demo/advanced.html) I noticed that they **set inline style within an inner div and apply scrollbar to the wrapping div**. So maybe that's worth a look as well.